# RSession aborted error on Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using windows 10 platform, now I installed R 3.3.3 console application then installed Rstudio 1.0.44

When i open the studio one popup when will raising automatically like

[image]

I changed the permission of RStudio-Desktop folder but still, it shows an error? could you please help me?

Comment: could you run R?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us probably a better place for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its an RStudio problem that should go to their support site.

Comment: I tried more solution on Rsite but I didn't get a solution

Comment: try to delete the `.rhistory`